# Cipher.init fails with UserNotAuthenticatedException in BiometricPrompt success callback

Tags: android, encryption, fingerprint

strong textI am developing the Android side for a hybrid Cordova app. We protect sensitive app settings with  fingerprint (allowing fallback device credentials).  This functionality is realized in a plugin, closely following the [Android developer spec](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth)

Without doing any changes to the relevant code, the Cipher instance cannot be initialized any more despite the Fingerprint dialog returning with success, and the Cipher initialization is well within the `userAuthenticationValidityDuration` (there are approximately 100ms from closing the dialog to the Cipher initialization with a authenticationValidityDuration set to 3 seconds)

The following code (slightly adapted by omitting all catch blocks and embedding small functions) is executed from the successful fingerprint authentication in the BiometricPrompt in `@Override public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result)`

```
private void generateSecret() {
    try {
        String alias = encryptionBundle.getAlias();

        KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT).setBlockModes(
                KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(VALIDITY_DURATION_IN_SECONDS)
                .build();

        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,
                getKeyStore());
        keyGenerator.init(spec);
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM);

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(getKeyStore());
        keyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey secretKey = ((SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, null));

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    ...
```

That cipher.init from the last line throws

```
android.security.keystore.UserNotAuthenticatedException: User not authenticated
    at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:712)
    at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:748)
    at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
    at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2977)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2884)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2789)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:956)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1199)
```

Fingerprint authentication worked before and I did not change anything in the Fingerprint plugin. I updated Android Studio and might or might have not changed Java or Gradle versions since it last worked.

**What change in my develop environment could have caused this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what exactly caused the behavior, but I realized that the error did not occur with another mobile device.

So I removed the device credentials on the problematic phone, registered a new lock screen pattern and a new fingerprint and somehow it works again.

I deleted my encrypted information on the problematic phone in a debugging attempt, but I fear that if this very problem occurred on a user phone, resetting the device credentials + fingerprint will make the encrypted data useless.